# You have an error in your SQL syntax - syntax to use near 'WHERE userId = '6'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE userId = '6'' at line 1

When querying these lines:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY created DESC ';
    $query .= 'WHERE userId = \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId) . '\'';
```

Can't find a solution. Do need to change in the column for the db or in the syntax?

Comment: You have to put the `WHERE` clause *before* the `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: you have to use the order by at end of the query and the query should be `$query = 'SELECT * FROM post  ';
    $query .= 'WHERE userId = \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId) . '\''; $query .= ' ORDER BY created DESC'`;

Comment: It is the basic concept of the query and you did not even realized it. Try to search first on google and then post a question if you did not find the answer.

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Why did you rip the query to pieces? You are fascinated by making things complex? Weirdo 

Answer (score 1):

Error due to use of `WHERE` after `ORDER BY`. The proper query should be as:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE userId = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId) . '" ORDER BY created DESC';
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors with your query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY created DESC ';
```

1. ORDER BY follows after WHERE in the syntax flow, so specifying a WHERE after ORDER BY is a syntax error (what you're getting)

   $query .= 'WHERE userId = \'' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId) . '\'';
2. You're not actually using parameterized queries. Get familiar with them and use them, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is only a bandaid to using proper parameters.
3. You're comparing a userID (presumably a integer) using string notation. That is pointless and may lead to unwanted results. Integers do not need to be enclosed in quotation marks in SQL.

"Repaired" Code for your query (still look up how to parameterize though):

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post WHERE userID = '.mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId).' ORDER BY created DESC';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try echoing the query? You'll see there's no space between `DESCWHERE`.

Move the `ORDER BY` to the end.

`SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE whatever ORDER BY whatever`

Also, read up on PDO and prepared statements, that code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

**use ORDER BY after WHERE. in query**

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM post';
$query .= ' WHERE userId = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $userId) . '"';
$query .= ' ORDER BY created DESC';
?>
```